# Why might releasing a managed object crash in -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _queueForDealloc:]?

Tags: cocoa, core-data, nsmanagedobject

I am occasionally seeing crashes with a stack trace like this:

```
0 libobjc.A.dylib 0x97dc0edb objc_msgSend + 27
1 com.apple.CoreData 0x97edcdc2 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _queueForDealloc:] + 162
2 com.apple.CoreData 0x97edccbe -[NSManagedObject release] + 94
3 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x9318ef38 CFRelease + 152
4 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x931a7460 __CFBasicHashStandardCallback + 384
5 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x931a706e __CFBasicHashDrain + 478
6 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x9318f101 _CFRelease + 353
7 com.apple.CoreFoundation 0x931bbc6d _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 253
8 com.apple.Foundation 0x973270aa NSPopAutoreleasePool + 76
9 com.apple.Foundation 0x97326fd2 -[NSAutoreleasePool drain] + 130
10 com.apple.AppKit 0x95087185 -[NSApplication run] + 627
11 com.apple.AppKit 0x9507f2d9 NSApplicationMain + 574
12 com.karelia.Sandvox 0x70001ef6 start + 54
```

Unfortunately, it's rather random to reproduce. Does anyone have any ideas what could cause such a crash? Doesn't help that no-one seems to have mentioned `-_queueForDealloc:` on the internet before!

I have a vague memory of a similar problem in the past where this was a symptom of deallocating a managed object while it still had KVO observers attached. Anyone concur?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Having finally been able to reproduce the problem on a development machine, it seems this crash is a side-effect of an earlier exception during context teardown.

The sequence of events is something like:

1. The `MOC` is being deallocated, so it's time to tear down its contents
2. To do so, all registered `MOs` are turned into faults*
3. The act of turning a `MO` into a fault sends KVO-notifications
4. An observer receives the notification and tries to act upon it, hitting a now invalid `MO` in the graph
5. Core Data throws an exception from the invalid access
6. For reasons unknown, that exception is not passed to my exception reporter
7. The `MO`s get released, but the exception left Core Data in an unexpected state, so the `MO` deallocation crashes

**In short the real problem is that observers outlive the context; don't allow them to! Any object observing a `MO` should probably also have a strong reference to the `MOC`**, like `NSObjectController` and friends do.

*I found in testing that Core Data often does this on a background thread, presumably to avoid blocking the main thread

`MOC` – managed object context
`MO` – managed object

Comment: That was a very thorough explanation. Much appreciated. This helped me a lot tonight.

Comment: @Mike Abdullah Hi Mike. I found same crash in my app sometimes. Do you mean that [[NSNotificationCenter defaultCenter] removeObserver:self name:NSManagedObjectContextDidSaveNotification object:_mocSS]; must be called everywhere? I'm using currently parent/child and old scheme (mixed) and i call remove observer from dealloc method in ARC. Is it or or i must to do it by call another function to be sure that observer removing?

Comment: @user170317 This problem had nothing to do with `NSNotification`s, but rather key-value observing

Comment: @Mike Abdullahi don't user observing inside my app.

Comment: Then you may well have a different issue. Probably best to post a separate question for it

Answer (score 2):

`-_queueForDealloc:` is an undocumented internal method. It shows up in stacks from time to time but it's nothing we deal with directly.

Your problem is most likely caused by over-releasing a managedObject. A managedObject will be strongly retained by a context that inserts, updates or changes the object so if you micromanage the objects own retention, you can over-release it prior to the context releasing it. This cause the managed object to disappear at seemingly at random. Conversely, you can over-retain causing an object to persist after the context has deleted it.

I encourage people to avoid retaining managed objects but when you do, put them a class property or a collection like an array or set. That way, the retention is handled for you.

Comment: So you're suggesting that I've over-released the object? Clearly from the stack trace, `-release` is being called, deciding therefore it's time to deallocate the object (I assume Core Data will do this when reaching a retain count of zero like the rest of Cocoa). But then as part of that deallocation routine, Core Data deallocates the object and then sends it a message? That just doesn't make sense! I don't think I'm looking at your run-of-the-mill memory management error

Comment: I think the context still has a reference to a managedObject that was killed in a prior drain owing to overrelease. The context still thinks the object is alive and puts a reference to it in the queue. It then tries to send the various delete and deallocation methods but the object is no longer at the memory address. Since "unmanaging" a managedObject and removing it from the object graph is a complex process with many side effects, the improperly killed objects causes a crash depending on the specific state of the graph at anyone one time.

Comment: To test my idea, remove any releases/autoreleases of the managedObject in code and see if the problem goes away. If it does, readd the releases until the problem comes back.

Comment: That's not really feasible. I have all manner of controllers that retain managed objects as part of their work. I know memory management inside out and don't think this is a simple over-release

Comment: Fair enough. I can only tell you what I have found when myself and others have had a similar error. I think that the function of `-_queueForDealloc:` is obvious by it's name. It is reasonable to assume that for some reason, an object in the queue for deallocation is causing the problem. Why that is, I can't say. Do your managedObjects hold references to any non-ManagedObjects or do they carry out some kind of side effect operations? If it's not retention of something like those, I've got nothing.

Comment: My logic is that -_queueForDealloc exists because Core Data handles its own retain counting. I assume this approach avoids blocking the main thread when very large numbers of MOs need to be deallocated

Comment: Thus if it was an over-release problem, I think this code would succeed (deallocating the object), and then you'd crash shortly after when something else tried to access the now dead object. I have no reports with that symptom which makes me think the memory management is fine

Answer (score 1):

We hit into a a similar issue when using a private managed object context inside an `NSOperation` and we ended up working around it by weakifying any parameters and using a private `@autoreleasepool`. I'll elaborate further below.

Our current set up has an `NSOperationQueue` which has a long running calculation we do in the background. The operation first creates a private managed object context with the parent set as the main object context and goes and fetches its objects.

In the mean time, we have a separate `NSOperationQueue` elsewhere that syncs down new data from our server, potentially adding, updating, or removing objects used by our calculation operation.

We first saw a bunch of these crashes out in the wild and the only way to repro it locally is to have both calculation and sync operations run continuously and after 5-10 minutes, we would see a crash similar to one of the below:

```
Thread : Crashed: background queue :: NSOperation 0x18f43c90
0  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36f11f46 objc_msgSend + 5
1  CoreData                       0x2928408f -[NSManagedObject release] + 166
2  CoreData                       0x2927b4d7 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 94
3  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36f201a9 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 404
4  CoreFoundation                 0x294713a9 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
5  Foundation                     0x2a1b6453 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 1058
6  Foundation                     0x2a25b44b __NSOQSchedule_f + 186
7  libdispatch.dylib              0x3746d651 _dispatch_queue_drain + 952
8  libdispatch.dylib              0x3746809d _dispatch_queue_invoke + 84
9  libdispatch.dylib              0x3746eba1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 320
10 libdispatch.dylib              0x3746fcd7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
11 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x375c6e31 _pthread_wqthread + 668


Thread : Crashed: background queue :: NSOperation 0x1db59e80
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x3722edfc __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x372acd37 pthread_kill + 62
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x371ce909 abort + 76
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x37258331 szone_size
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x36bf1621 object_dispose + 20
5  CoreData                       0x28ec571d -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue dealloc] + 80
6  CoreData                       0x28e5630f -[NSManagedObject dealloc] + 166
7  CoreData                       0x28e55217 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _queueForDealloc:] + 246
8  CoreData                       0x28e5508f -[NSManagedObject release] + 166
9  CoreData                       0x28e4c4d7 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 94
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x36c031a9 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 404
11 CoreFoundation                 0x29042149 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
12 Foundation                     0x29d88c23 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 1058
13 Foundation                     0x29e2dc1b __NSOQSchedule_f + 186
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x371505b1 _dispatch_queue_drain + 952
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x3714af85 _dispatch_queue_invoke + 84
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x37151b9b _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 338
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x37152cd7 _dispatch_worker_thread3 + 94
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x372a9e31 _pthread_wqthread + 668


Thread : Crashed: NSOperationQueue Serial Queue
0  libsystem_kernel.dylib         0x396871f0 __pthread_kill + 8
1  libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x396ef7b7 pthread_kill + 58
2  libsystem_c.dylib              0x39637ff9 abort + 76
3  libsystem_malloc.dylib         0x396aed25 szone_size
4  libobjc.A.dylib                0x390d93a9 object_dispose + 20
5  CoreData                       0x2e3d4081 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue dealloc] + 80
6  CoreData                       0x2e3655b7 -[NSManagedObject dealloc] + 166
7  CoreData                       0x2e364501 -[_PFManagedObjectReferenceQueue _queueForDealloc:] + 244
8  CoreData                       0x2e36437d -[NSManagedObject release] + 164
9  CoreData                       0x2e35b867 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 94
10 libobjc.A.dylib                0x390e20d3 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 358
11 CoreFoundation                 0x2e5294c1 _CFAutoreleasePoolPop + 16
12 Foundation                     0x2ef29999 -[__NSOperationInternal _start:] + 1064
13 Foundation                     0x2efcd745 __NSOQSchedule_f + 60
14 libdispatch.dylib              0x395c0cbd _dispatch_queue_drain + 488
15 libdispatch.dylib              0x395bdc6f _dispatch_queue_invoke + 42
16 libdispatch.dylib              0x395c15f1 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 76
17 libdispatch.dylib              0x395c18dd _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 56
18 libsystem_pthread.dylib        0x396ecc17 _pthread_wqthread + 298
```

We reviewed the code multiple times and was not able to determine why it was crashing. We tried enabling NSZombies, but would run out of memory long before we could get a repro.

What we ended up doing is the following 2 things:

**@autoreleasepool**

Inside our `[privateObjectContext performBlockAndWait:^{…}]` which resides inside our `NSOperationBlock`, we wrapped all the code inside an `@autoreleasepool{…}`. That way all NSManagedObjects retrieved during that block of code will be mark for release before leaving the performBlockAndWait.

**weakify/strongify**

Any parameters that include NSManagedObjects were weakify before passing it into the block, and strongify once in the block. This way since we no longer have a strong reference to them, they can be released if they become out of date while we wait for the `NSOperation` to start. Here's a good article on how weakify/strongify works: http://aceontech.com/objc/ios/2014/01/10/weakify-a-more-elegant-solution-to-weakself.html

Answer (score 0):

i has another solution so solve that bug. In examples, MOC properties for ARC looks like (readonly,strong,nonatomic)

After weeks of dancing about that time-to-time crash i got solution for osx (just remove nonatomic).

Now it perfect, all crashes go out.

Comment: That sounds likely it's only a temporary fix. It's probably causing your `MO`s to live a little longer, but a small change in circumstances will expose the problem again

Comment: This sounds like you're papering over your problem. `NSManagedObject`s are *not* thread-safe, so if you're relying on properties being atomic, that probably means you're mis-using your MOs by accessing them on the wrong thread.