# Crashlytics shows crash in _queueForDealloc: [NSManagedObject release]

Tags: crash, magicalrecord

I've got some crashes in Crashlytics with this information, unfortunately I don't know what to do with it:

[image]

I have really no idea where to start, I don't get any other information... In an other thread I see something like `[GAI threadMain:]` but I don't think that that's an issue.

I'm using MagicalRecord for my CoreData stuff, don't know what else I could say to get any information...

Comment: please don't vote me down only but tell me what I should improve/add...

Comment: Your crash is probably related to this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234139/why-might-releasing-a-managed-object-crash-in-pfmanagedobjectreferencequeue

Comment: @swalkner I am also facing this issue, did you happen to find a fix??

Comment: no, never, unfortunately... would love to solve this