# NSManagedObject dealloc crash

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-data, crash, nsmanagedobject

I got some crash report from my users, one mysterious is copied below. Unfortunately I could not reproduce it, so I can not give any peace of code. I'he not to much experience how to analyse this crash, I think in my app has a NSManagedObject subclass which is not retained appropriately (maybe it is with weak instead of strong?).

I've tried to debug my app using NSZombies, but it not helped (due to it seems to me that a message is sent to a non valid object).

Any idea is welcome how I'm able to getting closer the solution.

**(Thread 6 has crashed, not the main thread.)**

```
Incident Identifier: 00CFA055-D5C3-43B4-8FFB-C6DBFAB8DB91
CrashReporter Key:   890F7AB9-9E86-425F-BE09-12D9B1AEB42F
Hardware Model:      iPhone6,1
Process:         MySuperApp [10987]
Path:            /Users/USER/MySuperApp.app/MySuperApp
Identifier:      com.mysuperapp.mysuperappapp
Version:         528
Code Type:       ARM-64
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2015-02-14T18:00:23Z
OS Version:      iPhone OS 7.1.2 (11D257)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  SIGSEGV
Exception Codes: SEGV_ACCERR at 0x23cbbeb8
Crashed Thread:  6

Application Specific Information:
objc_msgSend() selector name: _queueForDealloc:

Thread 0:
0   CoreText                             0x0000000186176b5c TAATMorphTableMorx::GetChain(unsigned int&) + 12
1   CoreText                             0x0000000186183234 TShapingEngine::ShapeGlyphs(TLine&, TCharStream const*, CFRange&, TGlyphList<TDeletedGlyphIndex>*) + 324
2   CoreText                             0x0000000186182ad8 TTypesetter::TTypesetter(__CFArray const*, __CFString const*, void const* (*)(__CTRun const*, __CFString const*, void*), void*) + 192
3   CoreText                             0x00000001861828f0 CTTypesetterCreateWithRunArray + 88
4   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eafded8 -[NSATSGlyphStorage createCTTypesetter] + 1464
5   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eaf8efc -[NSATSTypesetter _ctTypesetter] + 332
6   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eb01b34 -[NSATSLineFragment layoutForStartingGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:minPosition:maxPosition:lineFragmentRect:] + 140
7   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eaf9a68 -[NSATSTypesetter _layoutLineFragmentStartingWithGlyphAtIndex:characterIndex:atPoint:renderingContext:] + 2144
8   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eb07874 -[NSSingleLineTypesetter createRenderingContextForCharacterRange:typesetterBehavior:usesScreenFonts:hasStrongRight:maximumWidth:] + 412
9   UIFoundation                         0x000000018eb38aac __NSStringDrawingEngine + 16812
10  UIFoundation                         0x000000018eb3a248 -[NSAttributedString boundingRectWithSize:options:context:] + 1508
11  UIKit                                0x00000001889ad868 -[UILabel _drawTextInRect:baselineCalculationOnly:] + 792
12  UIKit                                0x0000000188a1dca0 -[UILabel drawTextInRect:] + 524
13  UIKit                                0x0000000188a1da34 -[UIView drawLayer:inContext:] + 364
14  QuartzCore                           0x00000001885b4f7c -[CALayer drawInContext:] + 140
15  QuartzCore                           0x000000018859f55c CABackingStoreUpdate_ + 2432
16  QuartzCore                           0x000000018859ebc8 x_blame_allocations + 108
17  QuartzCore                           0x000000018859e758 CA::Layer::display_() + 1256
18  QuartzCore                           0x000000018857f01c CA::Layer::display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 240
19  QuartzCore                           0x000000018857ece4 CA::Layer::layout_and_display_if_needed(CA::Transaction*) + 40
20  QuartzCore                           0x000000018857e560 CA::Context::commit_transaction(CA::Transaction*) + 276
21  QuartzCore                           0x000000018857e304 CA::Transaction::commit() + 420
22  QuartzCore                           0x0000000188577c38 CA::Transaction::observer_callback(__CFRunLoopObserver*, unsigned long, void*) + 76
23  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018598f858 __CFRUNLOOP_IS_CALLING_OUT_TO_AN_OBSERVER_CALLBACK_FUNCTION__ + 28
24  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018598cae0 __CFRunLoopDoObservers + 368
25  CoreFoundation                       0x000000018598ce6c __CFRunLoopRun + 760
26  CoreFoundation                       0x00000001858cddd0 CFRunLoopRunSpecific + 452
27  GraphicsServices                     0x000000018b5b5c0c GSEventRunModal + 168
28  UIKit                                0x00000001889fefc4 UIApplicationMain + 1156
29  MySuperApp                             0x000000010011ee88 main (main.m:16)
30  libdyld.dylib                        0x00000001924cbaa0 start + 0


Thread 6 Crashed:
0   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000191ee81d0 objc_msgSend + 16
1   CoreData                             0x00000001856e0bd0 -[NSManagedObject release] + 168
2   CoreData                             0x00000001856d6aa8 -[_PFArray dealloc] + 96
3   libobjc.A.dylib                      0x0000000191ef1474 (anonymous namespace)::AutoreleasePoolPage::pop(void*) + 520
4   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001924b72e4 _dispatch_root_queue_drain + 596
5   libdispatch.dylib                    0x00000001924b74fc _dispatch_worker_thread2 + 72
6   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x00000001926456bc _pthread_wqthread + 356
7   libsystem_pthread.dylib              0x000000019264554c start_wqthread + 4


Thread 6 crashed with ARM-64 Thread State:
    pc: 0x0000000191ee81d0     fp: 0x00000001100b39c0     sp: 0x00000001100b39a0     x0: 0x0000000171e5a040 
    x1: 0x00000001858968c2     x2: 0x000000017aad6ea0     x3: 0x00000001925ffcdc     x4: 0x0000000000000001 
    x5: 0x0000000000000010     x6: 0x0000000175ccff80     x7: 0x0000000000000000     x8: 0x00000001928b1430 
    x9: 0x0000000023cbbea8    x10: 0x0000000000000000    x11: 0x00000088000000ff    x12: 0x000000014f060e10 
   x13: 0xbadd0ade23cbbead    x14: 0xffffffffffffffff    x15: 0x0000000000000001    x16: 0x0000000191ee81c0 
   x17: 0x00000001856e0b24    x18: 0x0000000000000000    x19: 0x000000017aad6ea0    x20: 0x00000001928d1000 
   x21: 0x000000019291e200    x22: 0x00000001928d1000    x23: 0x0000000000000000    x24: 0x0000000000000010 
   x25: 0x000000010e674038    x26: 0xa3a3a3a3a3a3a3a3    x27: 0x0000000000000001    x28: 0x0000000000000000 
    lr: 0x00000001856e0bd0   cpsr: 0x0000000020000000
```

Comment: Are you able to say something else on your configuration? e.g. Threaded app.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5234139/why-might-releasing-a-managed-object-crash-in-pfmanagedobjectreferencequeue

Comment: No matter what happens, I wish you peace of code! :-)

Comment: @ingaham I am also getting the same error and I am unable to reproduce it at my end. I tried using the Address Sanitizer but it didnt catch anything. Can you help me in this if possible? I am not able to figure out to use GD framework

Answer (score 0):

So, I found the reason based on [this awesome framework](https://github.com/GrahamDennis/GDCoreDataConcurrencyDebugging) for debugging CD concurrency. The reason was exactly the same as described [in this tutorial](https://web.archive.org/web/20150221025329/http://www.grahamdennis.me/blog/2013/09/09/debugging-concurrency-with-core-data/) in the *Autorelease pools and NSManagedObject’s* chapter.

Comment: The link to your tutorial is broken. What was the solution?